# How do I handle certificates when linking to Paypal donation site in android app?

Tags: android, url, browser, paypal, certificate

I have written a few android apps, but have never tried adding a Paypal donation link. The idea is: I have a menu. In this menu there is an option that says "Donate". When the user presses Donate, an Intent is executed to open a browser, passing in the url that leads to my donation page. I have tested the url in my computer's browser and it works fine. But when I press the Donate button in the app, the browser opens with this message: "The name on the site does not match the name on the certificate." Are there any special things that I left out that might be causing the certificate to be bad? Or is there any way to ignore the certificate (since it's obviously a mistake)? Thanks

Comment: Do you know what URL is opened in the browser?

Comment: Yeah I'm hoping it's the one that is hardcoded into the Intent. I went to my paypal account, made a donation link, copied the url and pasted it into the Intent for the browser. Is this what you mean?